# in my figma some shortcut key are not working properly

Tags: figma

in my Figma three shortcut keys are not working properly, so can you help me to add these shortcut keys on Figma or some other way to get it to start

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too, a lot. Usually it's about using non-Us keyboards. Sometimes I even have to change keyboards for the use of different applications. However, I found something that can be able to help you out,
checkout this link...
https://forum.figma.com/t/keyboard-shortcuts-aren-t-working/2727https://forum.figma.com/t/keyboard-shortcuts-aren-t-working/2727

I hope this helps. good day.